# Expresión regular para identificar un dato ingresado

Tags: python, python-3.x, interfaz-gráfica

Quería implementar una clase la cual tiene una GUI y un método. El método genera un identificador cuando el usuario ingresa una determinada matrícula del vehículo, de modo que, dicho identificador es personal y distinto para cada una de las matrículas ingresadas. La clase gestiona la entrada de vehículos. La fecha en la que entró, su matrícula y su dueño.
El dueño del coche se identificará por su DNI. Cuando entra un coche se genera un identificador para ese coche

```
import string
import random
import easygui as eg        



class Taller:

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = size
        self.chars = chars

    def id_generator(self, size = 6, chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


    campos = ['Nombre', "DNI", 'Correo', 'Teléfono', "Matrícula"]
    datos = []
    datos = eg.multenterbox(msg ='Taller', title ='Entrada de datos', fields = campos, values = ())
    cadena = ''
    if datos != None:
        for a, b in zip(campos, datos):
            cadena = cadena + a + ': ' + b + '\n'
    eg.msgbox(cadena, 'Entrada de datos', ok_button = 'Finalizar')       


    # devuelve una cadena de 10 digitos entre letras mayusculas y numeros
    print (id_generator(10))

    # devuelve una cadena de 8 numeros
    print (id_generator(8,string.digits))

    # devuelve una cadena de 8 caracteres en minucula
    print (id_generator(8,string.ascii_lowercase))

    # devuelve una cadena de 3 digitos entre el 1 y el 5
    print (id_generator(3,"12345"))
```

Comment: `_` es también un carácter válido en el nombre de la variable. En común lo utilizan cuando no se importe el valor de la variable.

Comment: Hola, aparte de lo del guión bajo, que como explica themylogin es una convención nada más, se usa cuando necesitamos declarar una variable pero no la vamos a usar nunca ¿cuál es el problema o error exactamente?

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos. Lo que necesito, es que a partir de la matricula introducida por el usuario, se genere un identificador para dicha matrícula. El error se presenta en el `return` del método `id_generator`, el cual me lanza la excepción `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. He probado también por medio de un patrón pero no termino de saber como tomar la matrícula ingresada, tenerla en cuenta y, a partir de ella, generar un identificador aleatorio

Comment: Por lo pronto  `id_generator()` es un método de clase, pero el ejemplo que has dado, pareciera como si no lo fuera `print (id_generator(10))`, no le estarías pasando la instancia `self.id_generator(10)`, de hecho te respondería esto, pero no entiendo como no tienes otro error en este caso. El ejemplo que has dado, ¿es efectivamente el que te da el error dl cual estás preguntando?

Comment: Sospecho que estás invocando `id_generator` con el número de matrícula de tipo `str`. Añade un ejemplo de uso de este método con una matrícula en concreto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo un poco de depuración en su código, he probado lo siguiente:

```
def id_generator(self, size = 6, chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    print(type(size))
```

Y el resultado fue el siguiente:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Dándome a entender que en algún momento el parámetro `size` es string en vez de entero.

Al usar la función `int()` para convertir de string a entero el error se solucionaba a medias:

```
for _ in range(int(size))
```

Porque seguia el dilema de que size a veces era string.

Entonces me me di cuenta de que el problema era causado por el parámetro `self`, efectivamente después de removerlo no tuve ningún error:

```
def id_generator(size = 6, chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(int(size)))
```

Esto se debe a que su función toma el parámetro `self` como primer parámtetro asignando size como segundo y chars como tercero:

> Nótese que anteriormente vimos que solo en el primer `print()` size es entero, y en los otros tres es string, lo cual corresponde a que en el codigo de abajo solo la primera llamada a `id_generator()` recibe un unico parametro entero y las otras 3 reciben dos parámetros, un entero y otro string.

```
# <class 'int'>
print (id_generator(10))

# <class 'str'>
print (id_generator(8,string.digits))

# <class 'str'>
print (id_generator(8,string.ascii_lowercase))

# <class 'str'>
print (id_generator(3,"12345"))
```

De manera que su función debería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
def id_generator(size = 6, chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(int(size)))
```

Y entonces su código así:

```
import string
import random
import easygui as eg        

class Taller:

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = size
        self.chars = chars


    def id_generator(size = 6, chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(int(size)))


    campos = ['Nombre', "DNI", 'Correo', 'Teléfono', "Matrícula"]
    datos = []
    datos = eg.multenterbox(msg ='Taller', title ='Entrada de datos', fields = campos, values = ())
    cadena = ''

    # Obtenemos los valores de los campos del multenterbox
    valores = list(datos)

    # Matricula es el campo en el indice 4 puesto que:
    # Nombre -> 0
    # DNI -> 1
    # Correo -> 2
    # Teléfono -> 3
    # Matrícula -> 4
    matricula = valores[4]

    # Generamos un id random de 10 digitos a partir de la matricula
    print(id_generator(10, matricula))

    if datos != None:
        for a, b in zip(campos, datos):
            cadena = cadena + a + ': ' + b + '\n'
    eg.msgbox(cadena, 'Entrada de datos', ok_button = 'Finalizar')       


    # devuelve una cadena de 10 digitos entre letras mayusculas y numeros
    #print (id_generator(10))

    # devuelve una cadena de 8 numeros
    #print (id_generator(8,string.digits))

    # devuelve una cadena de 8 caracteres en minucula
    #print (id_generator(8,string.ascii_lowercase))

    # devuelve una cadena de 3 digitos entre el 1 y el 5
    #print (id_generator(3,"12345"))
```